# How to make DrupalChat more stable, to have it recognise online users?

Tags: 7

Never had any luck with the [DrupalChat](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalchat) module. It is always flickering on and off, saying other users are currently offline when they are on.

Does anyone have any tips or tricks for making DrupalChat stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the module config page `admin/config/drupalchat/configuration` see **Chat List Latency** says

> The delay, in seconds, after which the user will be shown offline in
>   the chat list(i.e. removed from the chat list) from the time he/she
>   goes offline. Increase this value if you find the chat list is
>   unstable and keeps on changing a lot (for example - when a user
>   navigates from one page to another he/she goes offline and then comes
>   back online again). Decrease it if you find that the users are shown
>   in the chat list for too long after they have left your website.